# NodeJS fs API: Detect Asynchronous Completion

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs

I have a NodeJS application which uses the `fs` API to read files from a directory tree.  I'm using the `fs-walk` module to walk the tree.  For every sub directory encountered, the same function executes again to handle it.  (I don't think this is recursion; rather, the same function is bound to an event which is fired each time a directory is handled.)  Files are handled by a different function, which does stuff to them.

I'd like to execute arbitrary code once all files have been read without using synchronous or blocking code.  I couldn't find any way to keep track of the number of files in a directory (to count down, for instance), nor could I find any attribute in `fs.stat` to indicate that the entire operation has completed.

Had anyone found a way to do this yet?  I could find nothing in the node docs or on stack overflow.

Comment: I've done this in my module: https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/blob/master/lib/cache.js , check it out, it goes through the directory tree, cache the directories and files, save their stats and is watching for changes

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the `fs-walk` library a little closer, it looks like the third argument to the `walk()` method is actually a [final callback](https://github.com/confcompass/fs-walk/blob/master/index.js#L48). Internally they are using the `async` library, specifically `async.whilst()` and [`async.waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) methods which will execute the final callback when everything is complete.

I think the intention of the library creator is for that final callback to be executed when all async actions are completed. If that isn't working, you may want to [file an issue in Github](https://github.com/confcompass/fs-walk/issues) for it:

According to the code, you should be able to do:

```
var walk = require('fs-walk';

walk('/some/dir', someFileOrDirHandler, function(err) {
    // This should be a final callback, if the first argument is present, 
    // then there was an error
    if (err) {
        /* handle it */
        return;
    }

    // Getting here indicates success
});
```

Comment: Yes, but since I will never know which is the last file to be read, I could end up executing the final callback function prematurely.  This is because I'm walking multiple directories asynchronously.

Comment: Ah, but can you can pass an array of directories into the `walk()` method as the first argument? Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since there are x nested directories.  Why nodejs' fs API doesn't give a "children" count for any given directory is unfortunate :(

Answer (score 0):

As a compromise in performance, I ended up doing a total file count using a recursive function that accessed the file system synchronously.  Using the total, I then accessed all the files asynchronously, decrementing the total each time.  Once the total reached zero, I executed a function to handle all of the completed data.

```
var countAllFiles = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var total = 0,
    count = function (path) {
        var contents = fs.readdirSync(path), file, name;
        for (file in contents) {
            if (!contents.hasOwnProperty(file)) continue;
            name = path + '/' + contents[file];
            if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory())
                count(name);
            else
                ++total;
        }
    };
    count('/path/to/tree/');
    resolve(total);
}).then(function (total) {
    walk.dirs('/path/to/tree/', handlerFunction, errorHandler);
    // for every file, decrement total.  Then, if it's zero, execute the code that
    // depends on all the read/write operations being complete
});
```